# How to export powerapp solution (.Zip file) using powershell or pnp script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, export, powerapp, powershell-script

I need to download the PowerApps(canvas app) solution package(.Zip file) by using PowerApps PowerShell script or pnp script.

Anyone suggest me if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Per my research, there is no related power apps commands to export powerapp solution, we suggest you export it manually:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-powershell#power-apps-commands